# Speeding git checkout in Gitlab cicd for big repo

Tags: git, gitlab, cicd

I have a big ~6GB repo which I need to use for CICD using Gitlab. I am using default fetch strategy with

```
    GIT_DEPTH: 1
    GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: none
    GIT_FETCH_EXTRA_FLAGS: --no-tags
```

It is taking around 15-20 mins to checkout the repo. Is there anything I can do to make it faster.

P.S. - Caching is one of the way I think but here the checkout it self seems very slow.

Comment: It's not normal to take around 15-20 mins to checkout a 6G repo, even if the checkout files take 6G disk space.  You can try `time git clone --no-checkout` and `time git checkout` separately to measure how much time each command takes.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use git cache. You have to prepare cache as bare clone in advance and store it on agent.

and then

git clone --reference[-if-able]  ...

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone/